# Passing simple variable data (updating labels) in Swift between tabbed view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My situation is as simple as:

I create a new file (Tabbed Application) then I get the Tab Bar controller and the first and second view controllers (VC1 & VC2 respectfully) by default.

I place a label on both called 'totalCash' VC1 and VC2. In VC1 I do a simple equation. Say X = y-z. Do totalCash.text and update my label in VC1 and everything works great!

Now I'd like to learn:

When I update my label in VC1, how do I make so it that when I click the second tab in the simulator, the label in VC2 is updated with that value as well and vice versa. So if I 'buy more items' in VC2 and my totalCash goes down, it's updated in the label in VC1 when I click the tab and go back?

Comment: create a variable beyond the scope of viewcontroller i.e Global then access its value in both view controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depend on the data you set.  If each VC manage it's own data and all you need is update data in other tab, then use NSNotificationCenter, to send notification of any updates.

If all you VC share data, you can subclass UITabBarController and add a variable there.  Then each VC can call self.tabBarController.myVariableName.  Use KVO to monitor updates.  Like what Jonny said in comments

If the data is shared across the entire app, you can use singleton to share common data.  (singletons are hard to manage and hard to track changes)

Singleton Pattern for swift

```
class Singleton {

    var sharedString = "shared string"

    var sharedInt = 54

    class var sharedInstance: Singleton {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: Singleton?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = Singleton()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

Call Singleton.sharedInstance to get the shared object.

You can set or get shared variable like

```
    let shared = Singleton.sharedInstance

    let sharedString = shared.sharedString

   shared.sharedString = "hello world"
```

Comment: okay great thanks! so i'm quite new to swift, just in my third week of my course. How would I create a global variable that each VC can access? Basically the data is shared between all tabs but each VC has it's own functions. I.E. VC 1, overview how much money you have total, VC 2 store where it shows how much money you have but lets you buy items and minuses the cost of those items from total cash, which would be reflected in both VC1 and VC2

Comment: One last question, so I can get the variable sharedInt or sharedString to show up for my label in both tabs (which is great!) but if I update sharedInt in VC2 how do I then make that update happen in VC1 as well? Basically am I able to update the variable in the Singleton file

Comment: KVO,  see example http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/